# How can I make android application open activity depend on condition at application startup

Tags: android, database

I’m new in android programming 
I’m working on database application
I would like to know how can I  make application open activity depend on condition result 
The application will check for the database. if the database is created or not
If yes, open login activity 
If no, open create user profile activity

Best
Salim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(databasePresent()){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make an initial activity with no UI that checks some condition and launches another activity immediately depending on the condition.

See this answer on how to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856629/1369222