# Confusion in starting the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

In my app, for the first time i will create a custom user account picker activity, then from there i will start another activity.

Suppose user quit and restart the application, in onactivitycreated method first i will verify, user has already selected any account, if so i will start another activity instantly. In this approach i am unable to quit the application when user press back button.

Another important problem is, the app flickers for the first time during the launch. Any better approaches?

Comment: Sorry, exactly your problem I did not get you

Comment: you can use `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` for clearing history for timing that you want start another activity from first activity that check the user

Comment: and for second problem, if you check on onCreate() method, i don't think any flicker happened, but you can clear animation with ( `this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` ) and if you don't check on onCreate you can show dialog or toast or anything else on first activity, then start second page

Comment: i used this trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856539/dynamic-start-activity-in-android. it solved my issue, thanks